# Can two prepositions be used if there are two verbs in one sentence?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me which one is right?
If there is not any correct sentence, what would be the right sentence?
I do not really know how to write these kinds of sentences correctly.

> 1. She gives and receives advice to and from them.
> 2. She gives and receives advice from them.

And how about these?

> 1. She sings when she goes to the place and comes from the place.
> 2. She sings when she goes and comes from the place.
> 3. She sings when she goes and comes to and from the place.
> 4. She sings when she goes to and comes from the place.

Answer (score 1):

Giving and receiving advice:

First Set:
**She gives them advice and receives it from them**.
OR
She gives them advice and receives advice from them.

Second set:
She sings when she goes to the place and comes from the place. [FINE]

She sings when she goes and comes to and from the place [respectively]. [FINE]

She sings when she goes to and comes from the place. [FINE]

Simplest: She sings when she goes to and from the place. [most usual]

Also: She sings going to and coming from the place.

She sings **on her way** to and from the place. [simplest of all]

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.  If "She sings when she goes and comes from the place" is correct.  can I omit 'to' and just write 'from' only? I mean if there are two verbs like the foregoing sentence, can the first preposition for the first verb be omitted?

Comment: I had a mistake; "She sings when she goes TO and FROM the place". You can omit the "the" but not the "to". Sorry.

Comment: So can 'comes' be omitted?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The comes is implied, actually. "We go to and from work" in the truck.

Answer (score 0):

In the first set of sentences, none of them is correct. We should revise the way we express the idea.

> She exchanges advice with them.

or

> They exchange advice

In the second set, it is necessary to add an extra relative clause (clause starting with *when*):

> She sings when she goes to the place and when she comes back.

Comment: I am not sure that exchange advice is usual collocation.